# How can I use Import-CliXml to deserialize a generic list of custom class objects?

Tags: xml, powershell, deserialization, generic-list

I am trying to learn XML serialization in PowerShell. So, I am making a simple contact list to serialize and deserialize. The problem I am running into is that the `Contact` object is acting differently when I import it with `Import-CliXml`.

Here is what I am trying right now:

```
class Contact {
[string]$FirstName;
[string]$LastName;
[Int64]$PhoneNumber; }

$bob = new-object Contact
$bob.FirstName = "Bob"
$bob.LastName = "Johnson"
$bob.PhoneNumber = 1235589876

$bill = new-object Contact
$bill.FirstName = "Bill"
$bill.LastName = "Carson"
$bill.PhoneNumber = 1235589875

$ContactList = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[Contact]
$ContactList.Add($bob)
$ContactList.Add($bill)

[xml]$data = $ContactList | convertto-xml

new-item "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Contacts.xml"
$data | export-clixml "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Contacts.xml"

[xml]$ImportedData = import-clixml "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Contacts.xml"
$ImportedList = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[Contact]
$ImportedList = $ImportedData.Objects.Object
```

The imported `List[Contact]` has a collection of `Contact` objects, but I cannot seem to get the information from their properties. For example, when I get blank lines when I try the following:

```
$ImportedList | foreach-object { write-host $_.FirstName }
```

I know the objects are there because of the return I get from `$ImportedList`:

```
$ImportedList

Type    Property
----    --------
Contact {FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber}
Contact {FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber}
```

I am trying to get it to return the same thing as `$ContactList`:

```
$ContactList

FirstName LastName PhoneNumber
--------- -------- -----------
Bob       Johnson  1235589876
Bill      Carson   1235589875
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Skip the `ConvertTo-Xml` step, do `$ContactList |Export-CliXml` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is down to `import-clixml`, it doesn't return object type `[contact]`. `$ImportedData.Objects.Object` is instead of type `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` which is why you get blank lines here:

```
$ImportedList | foreach-object { write-host $_.FirstName }
```

as there is no property `firstname` on the object in the pipeline.

Instead of these two lines:

```
$ImportedList = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[Contact]
$ImportedList = $ImportedData.Objects.Object
```

Try this:

```
$ImportedList = @()
$ImportedData.Objects.Object | %{$ImportedList += [contact]@{firstname=$_.property[0].'#text';lastname=$_.property[1].'#text';phonenumber=$_.property[2].'#text'}}
```

Comment: Awesome! I casted the `PhoneNumber` property to `Int64`, and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tav for the clear answer. This is what I ended up using:

```
$ImportedList = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[Contact]

$ImportedData.Objects.Object | foreach-object {
$NewContact = new-object Contact
$NewContact.FirstName = $_.Property[0].'#text'
$NewContact.LastName = $_.Property[1].'#text'
$NewContact.PhoneNumber = [Int64]$_Property[2].'#text'
$ImportedList.Add($NewContact) }
```

**Update**

I was able to use the property names with the `Where()` method:

```
$ImportedList = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[Contact]

$ImportedData.Objects.Object | foreach-object {
$NewContact = new-object Contact
$NewContact.FirstName = $_.Property.Where({ $_.Name -eq "FirstName" }).'#text'
$NewContact.LastName = $_.Property.Where({ $_.Name -eq "LastName" }).'#text'
$NewContact.PhoneNumber = [Int64]$_Property.Where({ $_.Name -eq "PhoneNumber" }).'#text'
$ImportedList.Add($NewContact) }
```